# Static files with ASP.NET core proxied from subfolder

Tags: c#, asp.net, proxy, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

To learn and experiment with ASP.NET Core (1.0-rc1-final) I made a small URL-shortener type application. My intention for the app is to operate like "http://example.com/go/short-url" where all requests for "/go/*" are proxied to my app. I'm using nginx to do the proxy, if it matters.

The issue I'm running into is that my references to static resources like CSS and JS files continue to point to "/" instead of including the "go" portion. All of my static file references include the "~/" like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
```

I added a hosting.json with a server.urls entry set to "http://*:5000/go" which handles pushing the routes to "/go/something" but the static files still point to "/".

I suppose that I assumed that since the server.urls affected the routing, it would affect the "value" of "~/" but obviously that isn't the case. So my question is, what am I missing? Is there some other setting/parameter I can set to help the file references point to the right place? My goal is to have the "/go" configurable, so hard-coding that isn't a solution for me. It seems inelegant, but the other option I can think of is to put the "/go" into the ViewBag and just stick it in the href.

Thanks!